# What is the source of the verse that says that everything is established in yajna (fire sacrifice)?

Tags: identification-request, yajna, resource

> yajneshu devastisthanti **yajne sarvam pratisthitam**|

> yajnena dhriyate prithvi yajnastarayati prajah||

> annena bhuta jibanti parjanyadannasambhavah|

> parjanyo jayate yajnat sarvam yajnamayam tatah||

This verse says everything is established in the yajna. Is this verse found in the Vedas? What is the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I found the exact verse in the Kalika Purana.

> यज्ञेषु देवास्तुष्यन्ति यज्ञे सर्वं प्रतिष्ठितम्।
> यज्ञेन ध्रियते पृथ्वी यज्ञस्तारयति प्रजाः॥
> The gods are pleased by the performance of sacrifices, the sacrifice serves the people, the earth is upheld by sacrifice, and everything is rooted in the sacrifice. - *Kalika Purana 31.7*

> अन्तेन भूता जीवन्ति पर्यन्यादन्नसम्भवः।
> पर्जन्यो जायते यज्ञात् सर्वं यज्ञमयं तत:॥
> The creatures live on food, the food-crop grows by the rains, from sacrifice the rain comes into being, hence all entities are the embodiment of sacrifice. - *Kalika Purana 31.8*

Reference -

1. [The Kalika Purana translated by B N Sastri](https://archive.org/details/QCML_the-kalika-puran-translated-in-english-by-b-n-shastri-edited-by-surendra-pratap-nag-publishers-/mode/2up)

Answer (score 3):

The closest I could find was this, in the Mahānārayaṇopaniṣat:

यज्ञ इति यज्ञो हि देवानां यज्ञेन हि देवा दिवं गता यज्ञेनासुरानपानुदन्त
यज्ञेन द्विषन्तो मित्रा भवन्ति **यज्ञे सर्वं प्रतिष्ठितं** तस्माद्यज्ञं परमं वदन्ति ॥११॥

And in the Skandapurāṇam:

अन्नं प्रजापतिः प्रोक्तं स च संवत्सरो मतः ।
संवत्सरश्च यज्ञोसौ **यज्ञे सर्वं प्रतिष्ठितम्** ॥8.111.20॥

The verse is cited in the Śabdakalpadrumaḥ dictionary, under *yajñaḥ* (https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/simple/skd/yajJaH). Apparently from the Kālikāpurāṇam.

Comment: I found the exact verse in the Kalika Purana. Thanks for the hint.